# Snorby not display alerts on main page

Tags: snort

Building a Snort / Barnyard2 / Snorby setup.

Having trouble with getting snorby to see events.

Snort and barnyard2 are both running at boot.

Here is my config relevant to the problem.

Snort:

```
output unified2: filename snort.u2, limit 128
```

Barnyard2:

```
config reference_file:      /usr/local/snort/etc/reference.config
config classification_file: /usr/local/snort/etc/classification.config
config gen_file:            /usr/local/snort/etc/gen-msg.map
config sid_file:            /usr/local/snort/etc/sid-msg.map
config hostname:localhost 
config interface:  eth1
input unified2
output database: log, mysql, user=snort password=snorbypass dbname=snorby host=localhost
```

Snorby:

```
snorby: &snorby
  adapter: mysql
  username: snort
  password: "snorbypass"
  host: localhost
```

rc.local:

ifconfig eth1 up

```
/usr/local/snort/bin/snort -D -u snort -g snort \
        -c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort.conf -i eth1
/usr/local/bin/barnyard2 -c /usr/local/snort/etc/barnyard2.conf \
        -d /var/log/snort \
        -f snort.u2 \
        -w /var/log/snort/barnyard2.waldo \
        -D
```

Current status:

Right now, when the system boots, I can see both the snort and barnyard2 processes running as issued in the rc.local.

When browsing to localhost in a browser, I can login to Snorby and change password, etc...

I can also see the sensor listed under sensors.

When looking at the workers, there is one running. I have also deleted this from from withing the web ui and recreated it without any issues.

When looking in the database for snorby, I can "SELECT * from signature" and see alot of signatures listed here.

Also, I can see the size of the most recent /var/log/snort/snort.u2.1398021580 being constantly updated. 
My barnyard.waldo is also in this directory and I can see it with data and you can see that it is no longer a text file, but a binary. This can be re-created by deleting the file re-creating a new barnyard2.waldo text file and restarting barnyard2. By doing so, the file will be turned into a binary file with the size of 2056.

The file ownership is snort:snort and the file permissions on the directory /var/log/snort is 666.

Possible problem??::

The only thing I can see that is not functioning correctly is when I stop barnyard2 and start without -D to see the startup.

I receive a repeating error:

```
    --== Initialization Complete ==--

Using waldo file '/var/log/snort/barnyard2.waldo':
    spool directory = /var/log/snort
    spool filebase  = snort.u2
    time_stamp      = 1398023768
    record_idx      = 0
Opened spool file '/var/log/snort/snort.u2.1398023768'
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
Closing spool file '/var/log/snort/snort.u2.1398023768'. Read 0 records
Opened spool file '/var/log/snort/snort.u2.1398024174'
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
Waiting for new data
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
WARNING: No function defined to read header.
```

There is very little on this error when I looked through Google, but I believe that barnyard2 is having trouble reading the snort,u2 file. You can see here that it seems to load it okay, but that is about it. Regardless, when looking in the Snorby UI, there are 0 events on the listed sensor.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for this post, but maybe my response will help other folks...

Recently, I ran into a similar issue with Snorby.  After spending some "quality time" with the mysql DB, Barnyard2, etc..., I found that indeed the events were being populated under the Snorby "events" page, but not the dashboard.  The culprit was a disabled "snorby_worker" daemon...

**Quick "fix"..**
ubuntu - "systemctl status snorby_worker" --> if disabled --> "sudo systemctl enable snorby_worker"

I must have inadvertently disabled it when I was messing with my numerous senor configs.

So, with that being said, in your position.. I would first check the status of the worker service and if the individual events are being populated on the "events' page.  Check the status of the snorby worker service.  If disabled, enable it, and check to make sure that it started.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Once I ran PulledPork to down load snort rules, I received a new sid-msg.map file for the version of snort currently running. Repeating error resolved.